# C++ -- Code runs perfectly in Visual Studio, but a.exe in the command line keeps crashing

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've made a program that uses a linked list to simulate memory management, and it works perfectly when run in Visual Studio. However, when I tried to run the same program from the command line, that was not the case.

I copy-pasted both the .cpp and .h source files to Notepad++ and saved them, without #including the Visual Studio-specific header "stdafx.h".

Note: the program takes one argument from the command line before running properly.

And here was my process in the command line:

```
g++ pa2.cpp //this worked fine
a.exe worst //for the worst fit algorithm, tested fine in Visual Studio
```

The command line then outputs the first line of code, "Using worst-fit algorithm", before suddenly announcing that "a.exe has stopped working".

I have no clue how to fix this, and would greatly appreciate any advice.

Here's pa2.h:

```
#ifndef PA2_H
#define PA2_H

#include <string>

struct Node {
    std::string name;
    Node * next;
};

class LinkedList {
private:
    std::string defaultName;
    Node* head;

public:

    LinkedList();

    void create();
    void print();
    bool addProgramWorst(std::string name, int size);
    bool addProgramBest(std::string name, int size);
    int killProgram(std::string name);
    int fragmentCount();

};

#endif
```

pa2.cpp (not including main, which doesn't work with the linked lists at all, and some functions that could not possibly be causing a memory issue):

```
//sets a null node to "Free" each time it's called (32 times)
void LinkedList::create() { 

    Node * newNode = new Node;
    newNode->name = defaultName;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL) {
            head = newNode;
    }
    else {
        Node * temp = new Node;
        temp = head;
        while (temp->next != NULL) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        temp->next = newNode;
    }
}
//prints the linked list with formatting
void LinkedList::print() { 
    Node * temp = head;
    for (int counter = 0; temp->next != NULL; counter++) {
        if (counter == 8 || counter == 16 || counter == 24) { //new line every 8 nodes
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << setw(5) << left << temp->name; 
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout << setw(5) << left << temp->name; 
    cout << endl;
}
//worst fit algorithm
bool LinkedList::addProgramWorst(string name, int size) {

    Node * temp = new Node;
    temp = head;

    int fragmentSizeCount = 0; 
    int compFragmentSizeCount = 0; //comparison fragment size count, in order to find biggest fragment

    while (temp->next != NULL) { //find the biggest fragment
        if (temp->name == defaultName) { //if space is free...go through entire fragment and count up the nodes
            compFragmentSizeCount = 0;
            while ((temp->name == defaultName) & (temp->next != NULL) & (temp != NULL)) { //safety precautions to avoid null pointers
                compFragmentSizeCount++;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }
        if (compFragmentSizeCount > fragmentSizeCount) { //if that fragment is the biggest so far, store as the "biggest fragment"
            fragmentSizeCount = compFragmentSizeCount;
        }
        if (temp->name == name) { //exits early if program name already found
            cout << "Error, Program " << name << " already running." << endl;
            return true; //true == there is an error
        }
        if (temp->next == NULL) { //safety precaution to avoid null pointer
            break;
        }
        temp = temp->next; //move on to next fragment
    }

    temp = head;
    Node * tempTemp = new Node; //in order to go through fragments while still retaining position of the start of the fragment
    tempTemp = temp;

    compFragmentSizeCount = 0;

    while (temp->next != NULL) { //add program to the biggest fragment
        if (temp->name == defaultName) { //if space is free...go through entire fragment and count up the nodes
            while ((tempTemp->name == defaultName) & (tempTemp->next != NULL)) {
                compFragmentSizeCount++;

                if (tempTemp->next->name == defaultName) {
                    tempTemp = tempTemp->next;
                }
                else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (compFragmentSizeCount == fragmentSizeCount) { //if the fragment matches the largest fragment found earlier...
            if ((fragmentSizeCount+1) < size) { //if even the largest fragment is too small...
                cout << "Error, not enough memory for Program " << name << endl;
                return true;
            }
            for (int counter = 0; counter < size; counter++) { //fill fragment with program
                temp->name = name;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            return false; //false == there is no error
        }
        compFragmentSizeCount = 0; //reset fragment count so as to count up the next fragment
        tempTemp = tempTemp->next;
        temp = tempTemp;
    }
}
//best fit algorithm
bool LinkedList::addProgramBest(string name, int size) { 

    Node * temp = new Node;
    temp = head;

    int fragmentSizeCount = 32;
    int compFragmentSizeCount = 0;

    while (temp->next != NULL) { //find smallest fragment
        if (temp->name == defaultName) { //if the space is free...count the nodes in it
            compFragmentSizeCount = 0;
            while ((temp->name == defaultName) & (temp->next != NULL) & (temp != NULL)) { //safety precautions against null pointers
                compFragmentSizeCount++;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }
        if ((compFragmentSizeCount < fragmentSizeCount) & (compFragmentSizeCount != 0)) { //if the fragment is the smallest so far (and not 0)...make it the "smallest fragment"
            fragmentSizeCount = compFragmentSizeCount;
        }
        if (temp->name == name) { //if program name already found, exit early
            cout << "Error, Program " << name << " already running." << endl;
            return true; //true = there is an error
        }
        if (temp->next == NULL) { //safety precaution against null pointers
            break;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    temp = head;
    Node * tempTemp = new Node;
    tempTemp = temp;

    compFragmentSizeCount = 0;

    while (temp->next != NULL) { //fill up smallest fragment with program
        if (temp->name == defaultName) { //if the space is free...count up the nodes in it
            while ((tempTemp->name == defaultName) & (tempTemp->next != NULL)) { //another null pointer safety precaution
                compFragmentSizeCount++;

                if (tempTemp->next->name == defaultName) {
                    tempTemp = tempTemp->next;
                }
                else { //to assist with counting up fragment size outside this loop, to keep things consistent even if the first space is not a free space
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if ((compFragmentSizeCount == fragmentSizeCount) & (compFragmentSizeCount != 0)) { //if the fragment matches the smallest fragment found earlier...
            if ((fragmentSizeCount + 1) < size) { //if even the smallest fragment is too small for the program...exit early
                cout << "Error, not enough memory for Program " << name << endl;
                return true;
            }
            for (int counter = 0; counter < size; counter++) { //add program to fragment
                temp->name = name;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            return false; //false = there is no error
        }
        compFragmentSizeCount = 0; //reset to count next fragment
        tempTemp = tempTemp->next;
        temp = tempTemp;
    }
}
```

Comment: And where's the relevant source code?

Comment: Time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I'm almost sure you have some error in your program. But only you can can find it, as only you see the source code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that text: "Or if a rubber duck is unavailable, get another computer science undergraduate, it’s much the same" in the link you provided made me laugh so hard!

Comment: Are you sure you have all your dependencies in the path? If it works fine in the IDE but not outside, most probably you have some dlls missing. Checkout the Dependency Walker app.

Comment: From the first line, that reads `g++ pa2.cpp` I would deduce that you are using a non-MSVC compiler to "run on command line". The consequences of that are: 1) you are using different compilers, so you are **not** comparing apples to apples, and 2) chances are you are running a **DEBUG** build when in IDE and it is **masking** the memory corruption due to the way the memory management is done in MSVC's debug mode

Comment: So there's something wrong with the memory management? I'll post the source code...

Comment: If you look closer at your `create` method you will see a problem under the else condition. Think through what is happening there. You have `newNode` which you just allocated, then you allocate `temp`, then you set `temp` equal to head, so you leak `temp`. That means that every time you call create after there is a `head` you will leak one `Node`. This is probably not the source of your problem, but shows that there may be some memory management issues in the rest of the code. I would expect the VS debugger would have warned you about the leaked memory.

Comment: That's the thing, though, VS debugger hasn't warned me about leaked memory at all. Fixing that doesn't help, unfortunately. It could just be my side of things, rather than the code...not sure.

Comment: You should post the code that is building the list before you call you `addProgramWorst` or `addProgramBest` methods.  If `head` has never been set (which seems to only happen in your `create` method), then lines like this will be an issue `while (temp->next != NULL)`

Comment: @Seren -- You have functions returning `bool`, yet you failed to return anything in one or more code paths.  For example, look carefully at `addProgramBest` -- if that function falls out of the `while` loop, you return without returning a value.  That leads to *undefined behavior*, and I am almost certain Visual C++ warns you about that.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it! When I went into release mode instead of debug mode, I realized I had to properly initialize some variables rather than just declaring them. I then copy-pasted the code into Notepad again, and ran it in command line. So it was actually a very simple problem; very new to C++ (did Java previously), so I didn't even think that could be the problem. Thank you for the advice!